# Unity create a custom MenuIItem

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to add a custom menuitem to the main menu bar following the tutorial at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html, but I always receive MenuItem is not an attribute class. I did put the file under a folder called Editor directly in under Assets

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ShipFrameEditorMenu {

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Open Entity")]
    static void OpenEntity()
    {
        Debug.Log("Doing Something...");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing something. Like always, add your code!

Comment: I just added a very simple class I tried to use

Comment: Ok. Are you using any plugin in your project?

Comment: Not that I am awared of, so I think not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a custom script named MenuItem (maybe from a plugin or a complete project you imported).

For sure, try your script in a new blank project and check if the problem persists.

If that is, you shall find the problematic script and delete or rename it (and also update the name in any place it is called)

Comment: Thanks, there is a class named MenuItem that I am not awared of